# compilation error while maven install how can i solve this error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jpa

my pom is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.o7planning</groupId>
    <artifactId>springBootSecurityJPA-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springBootSecurityJPA-1</name>
    <description>Spring Boot+Spring Security+JPA+Rmember Me</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and the console is

> COMPILATION ERROR :  [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running
>   on a JRE rather than a JDK? [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project springBootSecurityJPA-1: Compilation
>   failure

Comment: what error? include error text here..

Answer (score -1):

The error says you are using JRE instead of JDK. Check your JAVA_HOME variable.

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-home-jdk-jre